# Should I include a synonym in parenthesis in abstract of a PhD thesis?

Tags: phd, thesis, writing-style

Should I include in parentheses a synonym I will use in the main text already in the abstract?

Example:

- The atomistic scale (micro-scale) shall be considered ...
- The atomistic scale shall be considered ... (Then introduce the synonym in the main text?)

Comment: Your university may have guidelines about this. Ask your supervisor. If not, use your own judgement. Does the synonym help with understanding the abstract?

Comment: I checked, university has no word on this. It would maybe help the reader.

Comment: Helping the reader is a good thing. Is the synonym better understood in your field?

Comment: Well, it is well understood in the field, that is for sure.

Comment: @Gamora thanks. That would be a viable option. Could you make this an answer with a reference of "wide" usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always edit an abstract slightly to your benefit using square brackets:

> The atomistic [micro-]scale shall be considered.

[It's a widely accepted way of editing abstracts to help with context.](https://writingcommons.org/article/inserting-or-altering-words-in-a-direct-quotation/)

[For example it's used when written news wants to add clarity to direct quotes.](https://www.theguardian.com/media/mind-your-language/2011/nov/11/mind-your-language-square-brackets)